# Sorted Data Structure which is efficient and can store the original message with the respective timestamps

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, sorting

I want to send different XML message strings based on the time. I have thought of implementing a data structure in JAVA and put all the XML messages in it with the time when they should be sent out. I want to use sorted data structure so that every time the message comes inside the data structure, it gets sorted and while sending out I can check their respective times and take the messages out. I want to know which data structure would be most efficient and how can I implement it. 
Also how can I put time in seconds with each XML string.

It is like:

```
Message 1, time to send T + 1  ---- put to the data structure
Message 2, time to send T + 4  ---- put to the data structure
Message 3, time to send T + 3  ---- put to the data structure....
```

There will be a separate thread that will check the messages in the data structure every second and remove all the messages which qualifies to come out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem properly. You want

1. To store messages which will be sorted according to time
2. will retrieve message. The message with earlier timestamp will be retrieved first
3. will be accessed by multiple thread..

If The above cases ae right then I think you will need a thread-safe queue. Because

1. As you need to sort based on time so no need to sort manually. as message with earlier time will be inserted first
2. it is a fifo.

In this case the [ava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) will be a good option

Comment: yes you are right in first 2 points but it doesn't have to be accessed by multiple threads. I was thinking to use maps. As a key I can use the time stamp and in the data I can put the actual message. Also it doesn't depend upon the time when the messages will be inserted on to the collection, I will use roll()or add() to set different time stamps to different messages. One message may have to be sent after 10 secs of its insertion, other may have to be sent after 20 secs of insertion. As it is not fixed so I can't use the queues. I have to put a separate time stamp. Can u suggest me a way. Plz

Comment: I think I can explain u my problem correctly in this way. I need a two dimensional data structure that stores the time stamp in 1 st field and data in another. This should sort based on the time stamp.. Now I don't know how is it possible.